# Archive Watch app application without iOS application

Tags: xcode, watchos-2

Ive builded a watch application for `OS 2.x`, and i wanted to submit the watch app to the app store without the iOS application. how can i do that ? what targets do i need to remove and so i can send the watch app standalone app without iOS ?

Do i have to submit both of them and apple will decide to take the apple watch application without iOS app ?

i tried to remove iOS application from targets. then the app stopped running on simulator. and couldn't be archived.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it. A watchOS application doesn't currently exist without a corresponding iOS application. If you are only updating the watch app, you still have to resubmit the whole thing, and the version of the iOS app must be incremented as well.